# How to get maximum values from pandas.value_counts for each variable?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am actually trying to get only maximum values for each year returned from the pandas.value_count() function?

I have tried using the apply function with lambda function but was not successful:

```
print(match_won_by_team.apply(lambda x : match_won_by_team[x].index[0]))


remove_duplicate_match_codes = data.drop_duplicates(subset='match_code', keep='first').reset_index(drop=True)

match_won_by_team = remove_duplicate_match_codes.groupby('year')['winner'].value_counts()

print('Match won by each team in respective seasons:- ', match_won_by_team)
```

I am expecting the output to display 2008: Rajasthan Royals: 13, 2009: Delhi Daredevils: 10 and so on from the series.

```
2008  Rajasthan Royals               13
      Kings XI Punjab                10
      Chennai Super Kings             9
2009  Delhi Daredevils               10
      Deccan Chargers                 9
      Royal Challengers Bangalore     9
2010  Mumbai Indians                 11
      Chennai Super Kings             9
      Deccan Chargers                 8
```

I am getting this error when I am using the apply function and lambda on it. 
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the data in ```match_won_by_team``` looks like?

Comment: To piggyback onto @iamchoosinganame, you should also show the line with "the apply function and lambda" so everyone can see exactly what you're doing. Welcome to SO!

Comment: `remove_duplicate_match_codes.groupby('year')['winner'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1))`

Comment: @iamchoosinganame: Here is the example of how the data looks like         
2008  Rajasthan Royals               13
      Kings XI Punjab                10
      Chennai Super Kings             9
2009  Delhi Daredevils               10
      Deccan Chargers                 9
      Royal Challengers Bangalore     9
2010  Mumbai Indians                 11
      Chennai Super Kings             9
      Deccan Chargers                 8

Comment: @Mike: Okay, sure. Using it for the first time so still learning.

Comment: @ScottBoston: Will try, thanks. Worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

I think you need to use the following:

```
remove_duplicate_match_codes.groupby('year')['winner'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1))
```

This will apply value_counts to each part of winners by Year and use `head` to retrieve the first record, or the winner with the most counts in that year.